# OpenLDAP Authentication with .Net over network

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, openldap, ssha

I'm developing a web application with a web service. One of the requisites is to authenticate against an OpenLDAP server. The password in the OpenLDAP service are stored in ssha512 (Salted SHA512). My problem is that I need the salt to hash the password in order to authenticate. I know that the halt is in the base64 String in LDAP and i know how to retrieve it, but i want to send them from the Frontend to the Backend already hashed.

I have the following stadard schema:

WebApp -> WebService -> OpenLDAP

And i want to send the password from the WebApp (Frontend) login page to the WebService already hashed.

Is there any tip in how to achieve this? I'm using C# .Net and html + jquery and ajax.

Sorry for the bad English. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using the supplied user name and password in a bind operation to the OpenLDAP server?  Edit: noticed you are trying to "pre-hash" at the front end - I don't think that is possible, as the salt is normally randomized.  Binding will let the LDAP server take care of the hashing.

Comment: And how can i bind it?

Comment: When you connect to LDAP, use the user's credentials for the connection.

Comment: Thanks, i solved this. Tomorrow i'll update this and answer the question.